# How to use HSLA colors with RMagick?

Tags: colors, imagemagick, rmagick, hsl

How to set an arbitrary HSLA color instead of `gray20`?

```
draw = Magick::Draw.new
draw.font_family = 'arial'
draw.pointsize = 12
draw.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
draw.annotate(@canvas, size,size, x,y, text) { self.fill = 'gray20' }
```

Also, using gc.rectangle, how to set the HSLA color of the fill?

```
gc = Magick::Draw.new
gc.fill ????
gc.rectangle(x,y, x + size,y + size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the RMagick [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imusage.html#color_names):

> Many RMagick methods expect color name arguments or return color names. A color name can be
>
> 1. an X11 color name such as "red", "chocolate", or "lightslategray".
> 2. an SVG color name (similar to the X color names), or
> 3. a string in one of the formats shown in the following table.
>
> ...
>
> hsla(h,s,l,a)

And HSL [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php)

> hsla(33.3333%, 100%,  50%,  1.0)   green with an alpha value of 1.0
>
> hsla(120, 255,  127.5,  1.0)       green with an alpha value of 1.0

So, use a string: `fill 'hsl(0%,100%,100%,1)'`